# How to fix lexical error: invalid char in JSON text. when trying to parse from JSON

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, error-handling, jsonparser

I have a problem with this RAW JSON generated from a script within a webpage of an ecommerce.

I need to parse it and extract information about the product

The same code works for other pages of the site but some products generate the error.

This is one of such problematic JSONs:

```
"\n\tvar products = [];\n\n\tvar _getAvailabilityText = function(available) {\n\t\tif(available != 'outOfStock')\n\t\t\treturn 'si';\n\t\telse\n\t\t\treturn 'no';\n\t};\n\n\tvar _getAvailabilityBinary = function(available) {\n\t\tif(available != 'outOfStock')\n\t\t\treturn 1;\n\t\telse\n\t\t\treturn 0;\n\t};\n\n\tproducts.push({\n\t\tid \t\t\t: 'IME5401' || '',\n\t\tprice \t\t: '22.99' || '',\n\t\tcurrency \t: 'EUR',\n\t\tname \t\t: 'Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu' || '',\n\t\tcategory \t: 'Riscaldamento' || '',\n\t\tcategoryId\t: 'C7301' || '',\n\t\tgroup\t\t: 'Riscaldamento' || '',\n\t\ttdId\t\t: '',\n\t\tweight\t\t: '',\n\t\tbrand \t\t: 'Imetec' || '',\n\t\tvariant \t: '',\n\t\tdimension55 : _getAvailabilityText('lowStock'),\n\t\tmetric5 \t: _getAvailabilityBinary('lowStock'),\n\t\tdimension63\t: '',\n\t\tmetric12\t: '',\n\t\tdimension10 : 'Piccoli e Grandi Elettrodomestici',\n\t\tdimension11 : 'Trattamento Aria',\n\t\tdimension66 : '',\n\t\tdimension62 : '' || 'no-promo'\n\t});\n\n\twindow.dataLayer.push({\n\t\t'products'\t\t: products\n\t});\n\n\t/*window.dataLayer.push({\n\t\t'event' : 'detail',\n\t\t'ecommerce' : {\n\t\t\t'currencyCode': 'EUR',\n\t\t\t'detail' : {\n\t\t\t\t'products' : products\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t});*/\n\n\twindow.dataLayer.push({\n\t\t'event': 'productDetail',\n\t\t'ecommerce' : {\n\t\t\t'currencyCode': 'EUR',\n\t\t\t'detail': {\n\t\t\t\t'products' : [{\n\t\t\t\t\t'name': 'Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu' || '',\n\t\t\t\t\t'id': 'IME5401' || '',\n\t\t\t\t\t'price': '22.99' || '',\n\t\t\t\t\t'brand': 'Imetec' || '',\n\t\t\t\t\t'category': 'Riscaldamento' || '',\n\t\t\t\t}]\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t});\n"
```

Here is my code:

```
  raw_json_embed <- json_data %>%
    str_remove_all("\\n|\\t") %>%
    str_extract("(?<=products\\.push\\()(\\{.*?\\})(?=\\);)") %>%
    str_replace_all("'", '"') %>%
    str_replace_all(' : ', ':')
```

```
ex_parsed_json <- jsonlite::parse_json(raw_json_embed)
```

At this point I get this error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {id:"IME5401" || "",price:"22.99
                     (right here) ------^
```

I have tried other solutions such as these:

```
  raw_json_embed <- json_data %>%
    str_remove_all("\\n|\\t") %>%
    str_replace(".*(\\[\\{)", "\\1") %>%
    str_replace("(\\}\\]).*", "\\1")
  
  raw_json_embed <- gsub("'", '"', raw_json_embed)
```

But I still get the error.

If I copy the whole RAW JSON into a JSON validator it doesn't find any problem at all, I'm clueless

Comment: That's not JSON data. That's straight up javascript code. What JSON validator did you use that validated that content?

Comment: I don't know `R` but the `JSON` keys should be strings, so try to surround them with `"`

Comment: @MrFlick I tried this: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: @Raphael that is the backup plan, use regex to extract parts of the raw data but I would rather keep the parse to json approach for easier handling

Comment: If I pass part of your object to that validator, it clearly shows an error. For example `{id:"IME5401" || ""}`. That's not a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trickery, this particular example can be evaluated in V8 JS engine as-is and resulting object can be passed through js `JSON.stringify()` to get a valid JSON. Though keep in mind that running random code is generally a **BadIdea(tm)** and it may not scale for your real task.

```r
library(V8)
#> Using V8 engine 9.1.269.38
library(dplyr)

ct <- v8()
# v8 does not provide Window, though script only uses window.dataLayer.push()
# and we can easily mock it with our own window object and array in it:
ct$eval("var window = {dataLayer : []};")
# evaluate the js string, script pushes product details to window.dataLayer 
ct$eval(js)
#> [1] "2"

# turn our fake window.dataLayer to json string
products_json <- ct$eval("JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)") %>% 
  jsonlite::parse_json()

# 2 objects that js script was pushing to window.dataLayer:
products_json[[1]][["products"]][[1]] %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 19
#> $ id          <chr> "IME5401"
#> $ price       <chr> "22.99"
#> $ currency    <chr> "EUR"
#> $ name        <chr> "Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu"
#> $ category    <chr> "Riscaldamento"
#> $ categoryId  <chr> "C7301"
#> $ group       <chr> "Riscaldamento"
#> $ tdId        <chr> ""
#> $ weight      <chr> ""
#> $ brand       <chr> "Imetec"
#> $ variant     <chr> ""
#> $ dimension55 <chr> "si"
#> $ metric5     <int> 1
#> $ dimension63 <chr> ""
#> $ metric12    <chr> ""
#> $ dimension10 <chr> "Piccoli e Grandi Elettrodomestici"
#> $ dimension11 <chr> "Trattamento Aria"
#> $ dimension66 <chr> ""
#> $ dimension62 <chr> "no-promo"

products_json[[2]][["ecommerce"]][["detail"]][["products"]][[1]] %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 5
#> $ name     <chr> "Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu"
#> $ id       <chr> "IME5401"
#> $ price    <chr> "22.99"
#> $ brand    <chr> "Imetec"
#> $ category <chr> "Riscaldamento"
```

Input js string, formatted:

```r
js <- r"(
var products = [];

var _getAvailabilityText = function (available) {
    if (available != 'outOfStock')
        return 'si';
    else
        return 'no';
};

var _getAvailabilityBinary = function (available) {
    if (available != 'outOfStock')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
};

products.push({
    id: 'IME5401' || '',
    price: '22.99' || '',
    currency: 'EUR',
    name: 'Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu' || '',
    category: 'Riscaldamento' || '',
    categoryId: 'C7301' || '',
    group: 'Riscaldamento' || '',
    tdId: '',
    weight: '',
    brand: 'Imetec' || '',
    variant: '',
    dimension55: _getAvailabilityText('lowStock'),
    metric5: _getAvailabilityBinary('lowStock'),
    dimension63: '',
    metric12: '',
    dimension10: 'Piccoli e Grandi Elettrodomestici',
    dimension11: 'Trattamento Aria',
    dimension66: '',
    dimension62: '' || 'no-promo'
});

window.dataLayer.push({
    'products': products
});


window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'productDetail',
    'ecommerce': {
        'currencyCode': 'EUR',
        'detail': {
            'products': [{
                'name': 'Imetec Living Air umidificatore Vapore 0,4 L 700 W Blu' || '',
                'id': 'IME5401' || '',
                'price': '22.99' || '',
                'brand': 'Imetec' || '',
                'category': 'Riscaldamento' || '',
            }]
        }
    }
});

)"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! I have also found that with these regex:

`raw_json_embed <- json_data %>%`

    `str_remove_all("\\n|\\t") %>%`

    `str_replace(".*(\\[\\{)", "\\1") %>%`

   `str_replace("(\\}\\]).*", "\\1")`
  
  I could use the json parse function without errors if someone else had the same problem

  `ex_parsed_json <- jsonlite::parse_json(raw_json_embed)`